# bash insert multiple lines into a text file including variables from an array

Tags: arrays, bash, file, printf

I want to insert multiple lines of text which include an array variable into a text file however it is printing the variable name instead of inserting the variable itself, my code is:

```
printf 'server {\n server_name ${cdarray[choice]} www.${cdarray[choice]};\n root /home/nginx/domains/cmmdm/suspendedpage;\n location / {\n try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;\n }\n}'  >> /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/${cdarray[choice]}.txt
```

IF the array variable contains 'demo-domain.com' the output should look like this:

```
server {
server_name demo-domain.com www.demo-domain.com;
root /home/nginx/domains/cmmdm/suspendedpage;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

but its coming out as:

```
server {
server_name ${cdarray[choice]} www.${cdarray[choice]};
root /home/nginx/domains/cmmdm/suspendedpage;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

Comment: Try double quotes (") instead of single quotes (').

Comment: thanks, as soon as I posted I thought double quotes doh

Answer (score 0):

Okay, easy fix, changing it from single quote marks to double quotes solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, changing from single quotes to double quotes *seems* to solve the issue. Yet, this is not how `printf` is supposed to be used. For example, if you have some percent `%` signs in your variables, you'll get weird results. Instead use this:

```
printf 'server {\n server_name %s www.%s;\n root /home/nginx/domains/cmmdm/suspendedpage;\n location / {\n try_files %s %s/ /index.html;\n }\n}' "${cdarray[choice]}" "${cdarray[choice]}" "$uri" "$uri" >> "/usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/${cdarray[choice]}.txt"
```

Each `%s` will be replaced by the corresponding argument. This is how `printf` is supposed to be used.